# Pinging the author of a deleted comment

Tags: discussion, comment, notifications, comment-replies

In the comments under the question [Prove $\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{c+a}}\gt1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3887110/290189), I found the notorious four-word question that I flagged.  It's [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/259305) as expected.  **Before** flagging, I pinged the comment's author.  Will he receive the notification if his comment got deleted?

Comment: It looks like the Comment's author replied to you.  Does that sufficiently answer your query?  Of course the reply doesn't *prove* that the ping succeeded, but I suspect if your Comment was posted before the flag, it would have gone through the normal process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some experiments, thanks to [my custom four-word question query on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/833784/what-have-you-tried).

1. I pinged the user before flagging: (s)he got notified as normal.  ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3926564/290189))
2. I flagged before pinging: the target user won't receive a notification because (s)he is no longer part of the ping-able users.

Comment: i am a bit new to this,but what does  no no longer ping able user mean?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore It's just my personal shorthand meaning "users that can be notified by `@name`".  More details about this type of notificaiton on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/259305).  The linked answer suggests that all users whose comment is visible can be notified with `@name`.  I hope that answer your question.